# Colocar campo para pesquisar em um Spinner

Tags: java, android

Preciso de um campo de pesquisa em cima do meu *spinner* para não utilizar a a rolagem na tela e economizar tempo para o usuário. Agradeço.

Código em que os *spinners* são executados:

```
public class FormularioMateriais extends Activity {

    EditText editText_matricula;
    Spinner spinner_supervisao, spinner_material, spinner_quant;
    Button btn_Poliform;
    Produtos editarProduto, produto;
    ProdutosBD bdHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_formulariomateriais);

        produto = new Produtos();
        bdHelper = new ProdutosBD(FormularioMateriais.this);
        final Context contexto = getApplicationContext();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        editarProduto = (Produtos) intent.getSerializableExtra("produto-escolhido");

        editText_matricula = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMatrícula);
        spinner_supervisao = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnersup);
        spinner_material = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMaterial);
        spinner_quant =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerQuant);


        btn_Poliform = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPoliform);

        btn_Poliform.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                produto.setMatricula(Integer.parseInt(editText_matricula.getText().toString()));
                produto.setSupervisao(spinner_supervisao.getSelectedItem().toString());
                produto.setMaterial(spinner_material.getSelectedItem().toString());
                produto.setQuantidade(Integer.parseInt(spinner_quant.getSelectedItem().toString()));

                if(btn_Poliform.getText().toString().equals("REGISTRAR AGORA")){

                    bdHelper.salvarProduto(produto);
                    bdHelper.close();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(FormularioMateriais.this, Finalizando.class);
                    FormularioMateriais.this.startActivity(intent);
                }

                 else{
                    bdHelper.alterarProduto(produto);
                    bdHelper.close();

                    String texto = "Registro Alterado. Consulte a lista dos Registros de Materiais!";
                    int duracao = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(contexto, texto, duracao);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });

        Button botaoencerrar = findViewById(R.id.buttonEncerrar);
        botaoencerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FormularioMateriais.this, Registrando.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Button botaodeletar = findViewById(R.id.buttonDeletar);
        botaodeletar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FormularioMateriais.this, ListagemMateriais.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
    public void onBackPressed(){
    }
}
```